# msgpack.exceptions.ExtraData When Receiving Messages Deserialization Error in Django Channels on AWS:

Tags: django, deserialization, channel

I am developing a web application with Django and Django Channels, and I have encountered an issue while handling WebSocket consumer reception events. When receiving messages from the client, the application throws a deserialization error: msgpack.exceptions.ExtraData: unpack(b) received extra data.

Context:
Frameworks and Versions: I am using an environment deployed via AWS Beanstalk with Linux 2023, Django (version 4.2.6), Django Channels (version 4.0.0), Channels-redis (version 4.1.0).

We have a load balancer to redirect traffic to a WSGI server (port 8000 where everything works as expected), and wss traffic to an ASGI server (Daphne) for asynchronous management.
Security groups are configured correctly and allow traffic as expected.
Elastic Redis cache service has been enabled and it works correctly (we persist and retrieve information without issues).

Initially, for the CHANNEL_LAYERS backend, I had selected channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer, but the connection was not persistent (the client connected and disconnected within a second), which was resolved by selecting channels_redis.pubsub.RedisPubSubChannelLayer.

Channels Backend: I have configured Django Channels to use Redis as the channels backend, CHANNEL_LAYERS in my settings.py
I also include  my current consumer code, asgi  and complete traceback

Expected Behavior:
I expected the consumer to process incoming messages without issues, but there seems to be an issue with message deserialization.

Solution Attempts:
I have verified that the data format sent through the channels is correct.
I have tried various different data formats, even hardcoding the message to be sent.
I have reviewed the Django Channels configuration and ensured that everything is configured correctly.

**Question**:
Has anyone experienced a similar issue or can identify what might be causing this deserialization error with msgpack in Django Channels? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```py
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.pubsub.RedisPubSubChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('cacheback-mbxa32.serverless.euw3.cache.amazonaws.com', 6379)],
        },
    },
}

Also, this is my asgi.py: 

    import os
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
import appProject.routing
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'appProject.settings')
logger.debug("Entra en ASGI")
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": get_asgi_application(),
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            appProject.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})


**Consumer receive event**

   async def receive(self, text_data):
        try:
            text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
            message = text_data_json['message']
           
            # Enviar mensaje al grupo de chat
            await self.channel_layer.group_send(
                self.room_group_name,
                {
                    'type': 'chat_message',
                    'message': message
                }
            )`

**And here it goes the traceback log:**
2024-01-16 03:46:33,676 No-IP daphne.ws_protocol DEBUG WebSocket ['172.31.9.79', 52020] open and established
2024-01-16 03:46:33,676 No-IP daphne.ws_protocol DEBUG WebSocket ['172.31.9.79', 52020] accepted by application
2024-01-16 03:46:33,676 No-IP daphne.ws_protocol DEBUG Sent WebSocket packet to client for ['172.31.9.79', 52020]
2024-01-16 03:46:33,677 No-IP daphne.ws_protocol DEBUG Sent WebSocket packet to client for ['172.31.9.79', 52020]
2024-01-16 03:46:39,226 No-IP daphne.ws_protocol DEBUG WebSocket incoming frame on ['172.31.9.79', 52020]
2024-01-16 03:46:40,053 No-IP daphne.server ERROR Exception inside application: unpack(b) received extra data.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/channels/routing.py", line 62, in __call__
    return await application(scope, receive, send)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/channels/sessions.py", line 47, in __call__
    return await self.inner(dict(scope, cookies=cookies), receive, send)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/channels/sessions.py", line 263, in __call__
    return await self.inner(wrapper.scope, receive, wrapper.send)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/channels/auth.py", line 185, in __call__
    return await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/channels/middleware.py", line 24, in __call__
    return await self.inner(scope, receive, send)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/channels/routing.py", line 116, in __call__
    return await application(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/channels/consumer.py", line 94, in app
    return await consumer(scope, receive, send)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/channels/consumer.py", line 58, in __call__
    await await_many_dispatch(
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/channels/utils.py", line 57, in await_many_dispatch
    await task
msgpack.exceptions.ExtraData: unpack(b) received extra data.
2024-01-16 03:46:40,289 No-IP daphne.ws_protocol DEBUG WebSocket closed for ['172.31.9.79', 52020]
```

Comment: In your development environment, install Redis and change the `host` on your `settings.py` to the local server, and then inside Redis issue a `MONITOR` command to see realtime data while posting messages. It may lead to a clue.

Answer (score 0):

I've done what Niloct suggested and I get in my local redis monitor this:

```
1705421806.387313 [0 127.0.0.1:38956] "CLIENT" "SETINFO" "LIB-NAME" "redis-py" 
1705421806.387603 [0 127.0.0.1:38956] "CLIENT" "SETINFO" "LIB-VER" "5.0.1"
1705421806.389391 [0 127.0.0.1:38956] "SUBSCRIBE" "asgispecific.2f346c113eab4adcbbc47be90003e250"
1705421806.389663 [0 127.0.0.1:38956] "SUBSCRIBE" "asgi__group__chat_test_group"
1705421821.303837 [0 127.0.0.1:44304] "CLIENT" "SETINFO" "LIB-NAME" "redis-py"
1705421821.303892 [0 127.0.0.1:44304] "CLIENT" "SETINFO" "LIB-VER" "5.0.1"
1705421821.305117 [0 127.0.0.1:44304] "PUBLISH" "asgi__group__chat_test_group" "\x82\xa4type\xacchat.message\xa7message\xb0hola mundo"
```

I dont get further information...

Comment: I created a new thread, once the problem with msgpack could be a first error, but the real problem might come upstream: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77841387/has-anyone-ever-successfully-configured-django-channels-in-aws-beanstalk-environ